# How to print echo statement in formatted as cat command in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, echo

```
    rm -rf xyz.log
    echo "Enter n"
    read n
    x[0]=ABC
    x[1]=DEF
    x[2]=GHI
    y[0]=MNO
    y[1]=PQR
    y[2]=STQ
    z[0]=RTY
    z[1]=LKJ
    z[2]=LDF
    for (( i=0; i<n; ++i ))
    do
      echo "${x[i]} ---- ${y[i]} ---- ${z[i]}" >> xyz.log
    done
    o=`cat xyz.log`
    echo $o
```

When I execute the above script, I get all output in one line, but in xyz.log, it's printed line by line. I want the same thing to be printed in echo command. Thanks in advance.

**$ ./val.sh**

Enter n

3

ABC ---- MNO ---- RTY DEF ---- PQR ---- LKJ GHI ---- STQ ---- LDF

**$ cat xyz.log**

ABC ---- MNO ---- RTY

DEF ---- PQR ---- LKJ

GHI ---- STQ ---- LDF

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483721/shell-script-printing-contents-of-variable-containing-output-of-a-command-remove?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing quotes in the last line:

```
o=`cat xyz.log`
echo "$o"
# ---^--^
```

Adding quotes will allow the shell to use the contents of the variable exactly. Otherwise, you're asking the shell to perform wordsplitting, where any sequence of whitespace (including newlines) will be replaced by a single space (by default).

rule of thumb: *Always* quote `"$variables"` except when you specifically want to not quote them.

Also, this is wrong

```
`rm -rf xyz.log`
```

You're performing the deletion in a subshell, and then using the output as a command. In this case, there is no output, but you can see the effect like this

```
`echo hi there` # -- command not found 'hi'
```

Comment: +1 as this is THE cause of your specific problem. Also, get rid of the ticks around the rm command line and consider using `$(command)` instead of backtick-notation.

Answer (score 0):

The -e option is used to enable echo's interpretation of additional instances of the newline character as well as the interpretation of other special characters, such as a horizontal tab, which is represented by \t. Thus, for example, the following would produce a formatted output:

```
echo -e "\n Projects: \n\n\tplan \n\tcode \n\ttest\n"
```

So use Your echo command like:

```
echo -e "${x[i]} ---- ${y[i]} ---- ${z[i]} \n" >> xyz.log
```

It will do the trick and will give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: `for (( i=0; i<n; ++i )) do echo -e "${x[i]} ---- ${y[i]} ---- ${z[i]} \n" >> xyz.log done o=`cat xyz.log` echo $o`
I changed it but still i am getting the same output.
**$ ./val.sh**
Enter n
3
ABC ---- MNO ---- RTY DEF ---- PQR ---- LKJ GHI ---- STQ ---- LDF

Comment: In the xyz.log, there is blank line in inbetween the output, but i want it to be printed in the output at the end of program.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-n` option on `echo`.  `-n` means "do not write a newline at the end of the line as usual."  It's documented in the `bash` man page.

I also suggest just putting `echo >> xyz.log` just to put a newline at the end of the file.

OUTFILE="xyz.log"

```
`rm -rf "$OUTFILE"`
echo "Enter n"
read n
x[0]=ABC
x[1]=DEF
x[2]=GHI
y[0]=MNO
y[1]=PQR
y[2]=STQ
z[0]=RTY
z[1]=LKJ
z[2]=LDF
for (( i=0; i<n; ++i )) ; do
    echo -n "${x[i]} ---- ${y[i]} ---- ${z[i]}" >> "$OUTFILE"
done
o=`cat "$OUTFILE"`
echo $o
```

Comment: Huh, I'm not sure how that happened.  I'll edit the answer with the *changed* code.  Sorry about the mixup.