# Replace string in a file with url present in another file in shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed, replace

I was like trying to replace a string in a file with the url present in another file using sed command.
for example...
let url.txt be the file that contains url:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483721/shell-script-printing-contents-of-variable-containing-output-of-a-command-remove`

and demo.txt contains
`Replace_Url`
the sed command I used is:

`sed -i "s/Replace_Url/$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' url.txt)/" demo.txt`

there comes no error but the string hasn't been replaced..

Comment: `sed -i "s@Replace_Url@$(<url.txt)@" demo.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be hard to do this job robustly with sed since sed doesn't support literal string operations (see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)), so just use awk instead, e.g.:

```
awk -v old='Replace_Url' '
    NR==FNR { new=$0; next }
    s=index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
    { print }
' url.txt demo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i "s@Replace_Url@$(<url.txt)@" demo.txt`
it works

Comment: That would fail given various contents of `url.txt`, e.g. `&` or `\1` or `@`.

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.